# Giving attributes to an object in Python

Tags: python

I need to copy the attribute of an array to another array that I'm newly creating. Here's my code snippet:

```
def mutation(self,ind):

    fitnessvalues = ind.fitness.values # saving the attributes

    G = Graph()
    G.add_vertices(nbr_noeuds)

    n = int(math.floor(1 + math.sqrt(1 + 8 * len(ind))/2))
    c = 0

    for i in range(nbr_noeuds-1):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            if ind[c] == 1:
                G.add_edge(i,j)
            c += 1

    for i in range(10):
        G.rewire(n=3, mode="simple")

    bin =  array.array('b')
    for i in range(n-1):
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            bin.append(int(G.are_connected(i, j)))

    bin.fitness.values = fitnessvalues # Wrongly putting the saved attribute to the new array

    return (bin,)
```

"bin.fitness.values = fitnessvalues" is not the way to go. So how to add attributes to an array in Python ?

Comment: Do you mean `numpy`?

Comment: That's not a NumPy array.

Comment: I changed the example to make the question clearer.

Comment: I think it's still not clear what you are asking for ...?

Comment: What I'm asking is how to give (or "set", the unclarity of the question might be a vocabulary issue as well) an attribute to an object (an array in this case).

ie. If I have an object named "bin", how do I give it an attribute named "fitness.values", so that ">> print bin.fitness.values" prints that value?

I feel that I'm missing something entirely, sorry about that, and thanks for your patience. Don't hesitate to propose suggestions so make the question clearer and more useful.

Comment: There are many unknowns: That is the type of `ind`? Is it the same as `bin`? How did you set `fitness` for `ind`?

Comment: ind is an array, and so is bin. fitness is set (I don't know how) by a library (DEAP, designed for genetic algorithms).

Comment: Are you sure `ind` is an array, what do you get when you `print(type(ind))`.

Comment: @BiRico, you're right, print the type actually gives me: <class 'dap.creator.Individual'>

I'll try your solution below, and be back when I have news... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python (and other Object Oriented languages), attributes are generally defined (the name and behavior of the attribute, not necessarily it's value) at the class level, not per instance. In python you can *sometimes* add attributes to an object which are to defined at the class level, but you cannot do this with built in types (including `array.array`). Lets take `defaultdict` as an example, all instances of `defaultdict` have the `default_factory` attribute. You can set the attribute by simply assigning to it or by using the setattr function.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
d.default_factory = float
setattr(d, "default_factory", complex)
```

You cannot add new attributes to a defaultdict, or to instances of most (probably all) built in python types.

```
d.new_attr = "some value"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/bagrata/<ipython-input-85-3fd77cc8678c> in <module>()
----> 1 d.new_attr = "blah"

AttributeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute 'new_attr'
```

You can subclass built in types, and define new attributes:

```
class MyDefaultdict(defaultdict):
    new_attr = None
d = MyDefaultdict(int)
d.new_attr = "some value"
```

You can also add new attributes to instances of `MyDeaultdict` because the class does not explicitly prohibit it, but you should absolutely never do this:

```
d.attribute_unique_to_this_instance = "some value"
```

Comment: This indeed answers my question, thank you so much!